# How to explain this incredibly slow socket connection?

Tags: windows, performance, tcp, winsock

I was trying to set up a bandwidth test between two PCs, with only a switch between them. All network hardware is gigabit. One one machine I put a program to open a socket, listen for connections, accept, followed by a loop to read data and measure bytes received against the 'performance counter'. On the other machine, the program opened a socket, connected to the first machine, and proceeds into a tight loop to pump data into the connection as fast as possible, in 1K blocks per send() call. With just that setup, things seem acceptably fast; I could get about 30 to 40 *MBytes*/sec through the network - distinctly faster than 100BaseT, within the realm of plausibility for gigabit h/w.

Here's where the fun begins: I tried to use setsockopt() to set the size of the buffers (SO_SNDBUF, SO_RCVBUF) on each end to 1K. Suddenly the receiving end reports it's getting a mere 4,000 or 5,000 bytes a second. Instrumenting the transmit side of things, it appears that the send() calls take 0.2 to 0.3 seconds *each*, just to send 1K blocks. Removing the setsockopt() from the receive side didn't seem to change things.

Now clearly, trying to manipulate the buffer sizes was a Bad Idea. I had thought that maybe forcing the buffer size to 1K, with send() calls of 1K, would be a way to force the OS to put one packet on the wire per send call, with the understanding that this would prevent the network stack from efficiently combining the data for transmission - but I didn't expect throughput to drop to a measly 4-5K/sec!

I don't have time on the resources to chase this down and really understand it the way I'd like to, but would really like to know what could make a send() take 0.2 seconds. Even if it's waiting for acks from the other side, 0.2 seconds is just unbelievable. What gives?

Comment: I am new to sockets myself, and I am also looking into a similar performance issue. Doesn't the OS add some overhead for error checking, routing, addressing to the message?  When you make a 1K buffer, just where in the TCP stack is that 1K? If at the very end (just before the wire,) could it be TCP or IP adds overhead to the packets and this may make the OS send and ack more then one packet?  On the other hand, if that buffer is just near your app, then it follows that the packet sent will be larger then 1K. I don't understand enough about sockets yet to know, but it is food for thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nagle?

[Windows networks with small messages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214397)

Answer (score 3):

The explanation is simply that a 1k buffer is an incredibly *small* buffer size, and your sending machine is probably sending one packet at a time. The sender must wait for the acknowledgement from the receiver before emptying the buffer and accepting the next block to send from your application (because the TCP layer may need to retransmit data later).

A more interesting exercise would be to vary the buffer size from its default for your system (query it to find out what that is) all the way down to 1k and see how each buffer size affects your throughput.

Comment: yeah, it almost certainly involves the acks - but 0.2 seconds is a geological age on modern hardware. I might just be able to justify taking some time tomorrow to fiddle with the buffer sizes as you say. That would be interesting.

Comment: @JustJeff, please post your findings too. I am interested in understanding this behaviour as well.

Comment: +1 1K is hardly worth sending on such a network.  I'm sure that the network stack would want to wait to see if it could assemble an 1.5K ethernet MTU, at least.  It is possible that the MTU is larger on some systems - there are 'Jumbo' 9K frames.